# Handling Exception throwed in a MediatR event ran as a hangfire job

Tags: c#, .net, jobs, hangfire, mediatr

I configured mediatR to run events using Hangfire simply like that:

```
public static class MediatRExtension
{
    public static void Enqueue(this IMediator mediator, INotification @event)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue<HangfireMediator>(m => m.PublishEvent(@event));
    }
}

public class HangfireMediator
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public HangfireMediator(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void PublishEvent(INotification @event)
    {
        _mediator.Publish(@event);
    }
}
```

And some more configuration to get started:

```
    public static IGlobalConfiguration UseMediatR(this IGlobalConfiguration config, IMediator mediator)
    {
        config.UseActivator(new MediatRJobActivator(mediator));

        config.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
        });

        return config;
    }

public class MediatRJobActivator : JobActivator
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public MediatRJobActivator(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public override object ActivateJob(Type type)
    {
        return new HangfireMediator(_mediator);
    }
}
```

And now what I call my API endpoint it calls:

```
_mediator.Enqueue(@event);
return Ok();
```

**The problem is when in the EventHandler (from mediatr) I throw an Exception. In hangfire dashboard this job is in the Succeeded tab as you can see below**

[image]

How can I tell hangfire to handle this exception and retry the job again? This job should be Failed/Scheduled. But this exception in mediatr event handler seems like takes the exception without telling the hangfire about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `Wait()` is the solution:

```
    public void PublishEvent(INotification @event)
    {
        _mediator.Publish(@event).Wait();
    }
```

But I have no clue why...